# Sort/ FIND And Insert Data in Vba EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in sorting ,
Are not correctly sorting, screening is only the first Number ??
Any solution for this or another solution for finding Number and Inserting Data?

**Lock This picture**
 [image]

File Excel: https://www.mediafire.com/?aoymmkqo1foaxqy

Comment: what's the actual problem? The data looks sorted correctly to me, given how the text is written.

Comment: Your data is properly sorted alphabetically.  If you want to sort first by the numbers prior to the dot `.`, and then alphabetically by the string after the dot, you can split the Category into two columns, sort by the numbers, then by the string.

Comment: This template Is Standar; But I want Please Any Solution For Example Find Number And Insert Data between Number > or number < ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
' Workbuuk
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

' Our used range
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.UsedRange
Dim rngCell As Range ' cellie

' Mad Max
Dim lngMaxRow As Long
lngMaxRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' The heat is on
For Each rngCell In rng.Range("B1:B" & lngMaxRow)
    ' set a value to the left, to the left
    rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Left(rngCell.Value, InStr(1, rngCell.Value, ".") - 1)
Next

' Sort on A, A, A . . .  .  under my umbrella, A, A, A, A-A
rng.Sort KeY1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending

' The heat is off
For Each rngCell In rng.Range("B1:B" & lngMaxRow)
    ' Undo weah
    rngCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""
Next
```

Assumptions:

1. Column A is empty
2. You want to sort by the numerical value, not overall string value
3. Category value format starts as XX.YYYY where x is a number, and y is a letter

Comment: Please check This File For Your Solution https://www.mediafire.com/?aoymmkqo1foaxqy